# Need help on reading and breaking down Algorithm into simpler terms for a beginner

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

Can anyone sorta ELi5 & help me understand how does this algorithm works? **According to the answer, the value is 3**. But I want to know the logic behind each line when executed.

```
What is the value returned by sequence_m([1, 3, 4, 5], 4)?

sequence_m(s, n) {    
  large = s[0]    
  i = 1

  while (i < n) {    
    if (s[i] ≥ large) {    
      large = s[i]    
      return large   
    }
 
  i = i + 1    
  }    
}
```

I'm also confused with what 'i' represents & what 's[i]' represents. Does 'i' refers to the integer in the array and 's[i]' refers to the count of each integer in the array? I do know that 'n' refers to the number of elements inside of an array.

Comment: `i` is just a number, `s` is the array of numbers and `s[i]` is the `i-th` element in `s` (start counting at `0` not `1`). Now, work through your 'code' with pencil and paper, become the computer yourself.  That's the best way to start to learn how small pieces of code like this work.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your code. You have `return larger`, but `larger` is never set. Do you perhaps mean `return large`? Also, I don't know where you got the idea that this code would return the value 4.

Comment: @JimMischel Hey, thanks for replying. Indeed it was a typo. It is supposed to be 'return large' instead of 'larger'. My bad, and by the way, this is a question taken from one of my school's Lab work. The answer may have been the value 3 instead.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, it helps a lot when writing the code down in pen and paper. Helps me to visualize better. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Lets have example where `s=[10,5,3]` and `n=3`

```
sequence_m(s, n) {
  // s is the array of numbers, [5,10,3]
  // n is the number of items in an array 3
  large = s[0] // selects first number in array, large=5
  i = 1 // is used for iteration

  while (i < n) { // as long as i is lower than n do something. First iteration 1 < 3, its true
    if (s[i] ≥ large) { // first iteration: 10 >= 5, its true
      large = s[i] // first iteration: large = 10
      return large    // return 10
    }

  // not executed, return was called already
  i = i + 1    
  }    
}
```

The alghoritm is going through the whole array until it finds number larger than the first one in an array. If it finds it, it returns it. If there is no such number (if array starts already with highest number, i.e. [10, 5, 3]) it will cycle through array to the end and then ends without returning anything.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - the first (from left to right) number in an array that is larger than the first number in an array.

Comment: @libik Are you sure about that? Where is `larger` assigned a value?

Comment: My bad guys. It was a typo, I have edited the code. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @libik I'll look through and analyze the code, thank you. I want to say I also appreciate the explanation on the right. It's so much easier for me to see it right now. Thank you once again.